# Map over State or prevState in setState?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have an array of objects which I want to loop through and reset the `selected` value for each item to `false`:

```
// Amount data state
const [amountData, setAmountData] = useState([
  {
    id: 30,
    amount: (30000).toLocaleString(),
    selected: true,
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    amount: (10000).toLocaleString(),
    selected: true,
  },
  {
    id: 70,
    amount: (70000).toLocaleString(),
    selected: true,
  },
  {
    id: 50,
    amount: (50000).toLocaleString(),
    selected: true,
  },
]);
```

What I was wondering is if the correct way of updating the state in `setState` is to loop through the current state directly (`amountData`) or loop through the `prevState` and if either way would have any benefit over the other method?

Using `state` directly:

```
// Reset selection
setAmountData(
  amountData.map(amount => {
    return {
      ...amount,
      selected: false,
    };
  }),
);
```

Using `prevState`:

```
// Reset selection
setAmountData(prevState =>
  prevState.map(amount => {
    return {
      ...amount,
      selected: false,
    };
  }),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to use the `prevState` when updating state based on the previous state in React. Because React state updates may be asynchronous, and if you rely on the current state directly, you might end up with stale or incorrect state values.

Using `prevState` ensures that you're always working with the most up-to-date state values when making updates.
So you should use `prevState` which is safer and guarantees that you're working with the correct state values when updating the `amountData` state.

```
// Reset selection
setAmountData(prevState =>
  prevState.map(amount => {
    return {
      ...amount,
      selected: false,
    };
  }),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [React docs](https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates) , if you just pass on the next state's value  to a setState, and have multiple such setStates in your handler, all of them get batched, and only one gets applied to your state value.

However, passing a function that takes the prevState, and applies changes to the state variable based on whatever that value is, does not cause this batching.

In your case, since you only have setState once, both the methods yield the same result.

I have gone ahead and created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-williams-p9p7q2?file=/src/App.js) where you can experiment with my code and look at the console to better understand this.

Answer (score 0):

You really only need to use the `setState(prevState => ...)` synthax if you have multiple `setState` calls in a row.

There is no recommendation to always use this synthax, it's a matter of preference. See https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#is-using-an-updater-always-preferred

> You might hear a recommendation to always write code like setAge(a => a + 1) if the state you’re setting is calculated from the previous state. There is no harm in it, but it is also not always necessary.
> [...]
> If you prefer consistency over slightly more verbose syntax, it’s reasonable to always write an updater if the state you’re setting is calculated from the previous state.